# Way to simplify an inequality with many variables

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, inequalities

my problem is the following:

I have three inequalities in five variables $x,u,a,b,c\in \mathbb{R},x>0 $:

```
a/x >= +c + (1/(x))*Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2]

2*(u*b + c)/(u^2 + 1) >=  a/x + c + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) 
                           - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2]

2*((u - x)*(b - a) + c)/((u - x)^2 + 1) >=  a/x + c + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1)
                                            - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2]
```

**I need to find conditions on $x$ and $u$ such that for every value of $a,b,c$ the following inequality is satisfied:**

```
  Max[2*a/x,2*(u*b + c)/(u^2 + 1), 2*((u - x)*(b - a)
  + c)/((u - x)^2 + 1)] >= a/x+ c + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) 
  - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2]
```

My idea was to use the command

```
Simplify[Reduce[{Max[2*a/x,2*(u*b + c)/(u^2 + 1), 2*((u - x)*(b - a)
  + c)/((u - x)^2 + 1)] >= a/x+ c + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) 
  - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2],x>0}, {x, u, a, b, c}]]
```

and search for a condition only with $x$ and $u$.

The only problem is that Mathematica seems to run out of memory: it starts running and computing and never ends.. I guess the condition with the Max is too hard to compute. **Do you know if there is a lighter (in terms of computational power) way to solve the problem?**

EDIT: **x<0 is not acceptable as an answer because I consider only x>0**

Comment: Please post the expressions as copyable code snippets, so we can try.

Comment: ok, now it is better?

Comment: If you wrap the inequalities in backticks `like this` its perfect :) Or you can highlight the expressions and press the {} button in the question editor.

Comment: I find your question is not quite clear. ...to find conditions on `u` and `v`? There is `x` , not `v`. Moreover expressions could be simplified at least a bit. No condition on `u`?  Where does this problem come from?

Comment: sorry, it was "conditions on $x$ and $u$. I need to find $x$ and $u$ such that at least one of the inequalities is satisfied for every value of $a$ and $b$ and $c$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @user294185 Now a bit more, but there is `2a/x` and `a/x`  at the both sides of the first inequality.  Motivations for the problem might be also interesting.

Comment: Yes, now it's fixed. It was made so to make the expression with Max simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will work much faster if you define a domain for `a,b,c`. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of Conditionals.

for example

```
con1 = (2*a/x >=  a/x + c + (1/(x))*Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) 
        - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2])
con2 = (2*(u*b + c)/(u^2 + 1) >= a/x + c + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1)  
        - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2])
con3 = (2*((u - x)*(b - a) + c)/((u - x)^2 + 1) >=  a/x + c 
        + (1/(x))* Sqrt[a^2*(u^2 + 1) - 2*a*(b*u + c)*x + (b^2 + c^2)*x^2])
```

And what you are asking is

```
Reduce[con1 || con2 || con3, {x, u}, Reals]
```

I am not sure if there is a global solution and running for ages. So next best think I can do is define a domain. Lets take two conditions at a time

```
s2 = Reduce[con1 || con2, {x, u}, Reals]
```

will give you a large numbers of conditions and you can see that their is no unique result. So I define a domain, say `a>b>c>0`

```
Assuming[{a > b > c > 0}, Simplify[s2]]
```

Gives you a definite result. You can scan different ranges to get a full picture.

**Visual Solution**

Sometimes a visual method comes handy (it is a quack indeed). You just plot and check the solution.

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
  RegionPlot[Block[{a = a0, b = b0, c = c0}, con1], {x, -10, 10}, {u, -10, 10}
  ,ImageSize -> 200],
  RegionPlot[Block[{a = a0, b = b0, c = c0}, con2], {x, -10, 10}, {u, -10, 10}
  ,ImageSize -> 200],
  RegionPlot[Block[{a = a0, b = b0, c = c0}, con3], {x, -10, 10}, {u, -10, 10}
  ,ImageSize -> 200]
  }] , {a0, 0, 1}, {b0, 0, 1}, {c0, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

As you can see `x<0` satisfy all cases. You can further verify with `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[Block[{a = 0.1, b = 0.1, c = 0.2}, {con1 || con2 || con3}], {x, u}, Reals]
```

> x<0

or you can put it in `Manipulate`.

Comment: At least one of ineaqualities has to be satisfied for any real `a, b, c`. Conditions are to be imposed on `x` and `u` and not on `a, b, c`. It seems you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, Artes is right. Also, I'm sorry but I edited the question, because actually I need the Max to be greater than the expression with the square root

Comment: I am not sure if a global solution exists in this case. So probably the best choice is scanning different region and combine them. This is the best I can do in that case :|

Comment: Defining regions for $a$, $b$ and $c$ is not a problem. But what I do need is a result with conditions **only for x and u, in which a,b,c don't appear**. If I compile the code you wrote I get conditions with $a,b,c$

Comment: Another problem is that if I try to do s2 = Reduce[con1 || con2 || con3, {x, u}, Reals] I get the same problem of Mathematica running indefinitely..

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the visual solution, but a condition was $x>=0$ (It was written in the question, at least this time it's not my fault :) )